# Can I use the Pods Form block but set a specific value for one of my pod's fields?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-shortcode

Trying to expose some content creation to website visitors through Pods Forms. Specifically, I have an "Individual" content type that I would allow visitors to create, but I want to control which "committee" (another content type) the newly created "individual" is a member of. I see I can use a URL parameter in the admin GUI, but I don't see how to do the same thing if I am exposing the creation process to the public site.

Is it possible?

Attached is the GUI options for a Pod Form block, which I hope clarifies what I am trying to do.

[image]

I tried adding a URL parameter to the pod field and then setting that parameter on the page with the exposed pod form block, but I kept getting a 404 for the page, so long as I had any sort of URL parameter added to the slug.

Comment: Hu. Adding other URL parameters doesn't lead to a 404. It is only the URL parameter I specify in the Pod's field definition. Again, it works just fine through the admin GUI view of the pod creation, but not when I add the form to a page.

Comment: Also not a problem for normal fields. Something about the field being a relationship between two pod types leads to the 404 error.